# store mail id's in to an array using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a HTML DOM string as below

```
<div><p>Hello,</p> <p>For the following campaign: </p>
<div style="margin-left:50px">
<strong>Account:</strong> BLT+ Digital [ID: 11641] <br>
<strong>Advertiser:</strong> OWN [ID: 23512576] <br> 
<strong>Campaign:</strong> Greenleaf [ID: 43551067]</div>
<p></p> 
<p>...the following creatives have been published to QA and are ready  
for review:</p>
<div style="margin-left:50px"><p>
<strong>Creative:</strong>own_greenleaf_970x250_ROS [ID: 43588775] <br> <strong>Format/Dimensions:</strong> INPAGE[970x250]
<br> <strong>Mode: </strong> HTML5</p></div>
<p><strong>Publisher:</strong> <a>fanaya@bltomato.com</a></p>
<p><strong>CCed:</strong>
<a>drm-support-us@google.com</a>, <a>fanaya.blt@gmail.com</a>
</p>
<p>After QA approves the creatives, if an advertiser association is in place, the creatives can be transferred to the associated advertiser’s creative library.</p> <p>If you're using DoubleClick's QA services, please contact your campaign manager to coordinate the next steps in the QA process.</p>
<p>Custom message:</p><div style="margin-left:50px"><p>
</p></div>
<p>Questions? Visit our help center at <a href="http://www.google.com/support/richmedia/" 
target="_blank">http://www.google.com/support/<wbr>richmedia/</a>.</p> <p>If you still have questions after visiting the help center, or if you believe you received this email in error, please go to <a href="https://support.google.com/richmedia/#contact=1" target="_blank">https://support.google.com/<wbr>richmedia/#contact=1</a>.</p> <p>Regards,<br> The DoubleClick Studio team</p></div>
```

I have to store the mail id's in to array like this

```
var mail_ids = [
'example_id@google.com',
'example_id@gmail.com',
'example_id_another@gmail.com'
];
```

Can any one help me with the regex for doing so.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Are they always in `<a></a>` tags? If so, just loop through the tags and add to array

Comment: Thanks darren. But I'm having more number of <a> tags inside the <p> tag with some links other than mail-id's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is that what are you looking for ?

```
$(document).text().match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi)
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/53aoa00t/)